# Is there any way to remove all default paddings all over the project?

Tags: flutter

Hey I was working with the drawer object and all the items given as children have a default padding so the need is as follows:

As a developer I would like to specify my own padding dimensions on the objects so I can design the app as I would like.

Second questions: is there any way to reposition the object already rendered?

Answer (score 0):

For your frist question, you can wrap your `Drawer` items within a `Padding` widget, and specify the type of padding you want in `padding` property.

Here is a simple example playing around with the left padding  (0.0 to 20.0 to 80.0).

[image]

```
drawer: new Drawer(
        child: new ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            new DrawerHeader(child: new Container()),
            new Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 80.0),
              child: new ListTile(
                leading: new Icon(Icons.account_box, color: Colors.blue),),)

          ],
        ),

      )
```

**Update**
If you wish not to use a `ListTile` and compose your customization icons, the following example might be a good starting point for you.

[image]

```
drawer: new Drawer(
        child: new ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            new DrawerHeader(child: new Container()),
                new Align(alignment:FractionalOffset.centerLeft,child: new Icon(Icons.account_box, color: Colors.blue),),

          ],
        ),
      )
```

---

As far as your second question go, you need to add more details about what are you trying to achieve, generally speaking, yes you can re-position a `StatefulWidget` by changing the `state` of it in a `setState` call, it seems that the second question is irrelevant to the padding one, so I would recommend creating a separate question for this one and add more details to it.

Comment: As you see the icon has a margin on the left by default. That is my main problem, all elements have a margin or dimension already set without the possibility to customize it. The only option would be to extend every class and implement custom dimensions ?

Comment: This is because we are using a `ListTile` in this example and feeding the icon to its `leading` property which is designed this way by default, if you wish to reconstruct everything from scratch and have full control over the positioning, then you should compose your own widget and not use predefined ones.

Comment: I have added a bit more details on how to achieve this in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your second question: This is not intended because the paddings are a essential part of material design. Removing all the paddings would defy the purpose of creating UIs with material design build into the widgets.